# Sublime Text - plugin_host exited unexpectedly after installing sublime_tern

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, tern

I have installed sublime_tern package to help me with my MeteorJS development.
After installing this package, any time I start Sublime I get:  plugin_host exited unexpectedly.
What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Here is the console output:  Starting TernJS server for /Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/meteor/model-test/ModelTest.sublime-project with 4 libs and 98 files
resource not found
error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted

Comment: Did you drop the meteor.js plugin into Packages/TernJS/ternjs/plugin? (https://github.com/Slava/tern-meteor)

Answer (score 4):

## Problem

I just had this problem but it turned out that it resulted from copying sublime between my two laptops. Somewhere along the line I lost the correct permissions.

## Solution

The solution for me was to give execution permissions on `plugin_host` and it was fine (I also had to do that for the `sublime_text` binary, I just realised that faster).

Copy pasters, navigate to your sublime folder (see below for possible paths) and run:

```
chmod 755 sublime_text
chmod 755 plugin_host
```

*(if you don't know how to navigate on the command line, you probably shouldn't be copy pasting)*

## Possible Paths

If you're on Mac it could be something like `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS`

On Linux, mine is `/opt/sublime_text_3`

Comment: I'm having this problem too, could you please explain how you solved it ? (How you gave execution permissions to plugin_host)

Comment: I am using Windows, so I tried the chmod alternative i.e. calcs, but it did not work :(

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB Google to find out how to change permissions on your version of windows and then ensure that everyone (owner, group, and others) has execute permissions on those two files.

Comment: On Linux Ubuntu 18, I changed the permissions flags to 755 as suggested above and also change dthe group (from root to users). Now, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem as you did. However, I downloaded and installed newer (sub)version of sublime to same directory where was older version installed. That confused sublime and finally I solved this issue by uninstalling sublime using revo uninstaller and installing it again.

Hope I've been of some help.