# Sublime Text 3: "plugin host has exited unexpectedly"

Tags: plugins, sublimetext, sublimetext3, package-control

I currently use Sublime Text 3. Today this "plugin host has exited unexpectedly" thing started to show up, and after having restarted ST several times, I decided to uninstall it. Now I've reinstalled it, but I can't even install the Package Control because "plugin host has exited unexpectedly" continues to show up.

In the console I've found:

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282' + 'd0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) 
error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted
```

I'm using Yosemite, so can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you have a permissions issue (usually due to copying the app around).

[This other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26044247/5552584) has the solution you're looking for.

In terminal navigate to `/path/to/your/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS` then change the permissions from whatever they are to 755.
`chmod 755 plugin_host`
Do the same for the Sublime Text executable as well.
`chmod 755 Sublime\ Text`

Answer (score 2):

There might be issue with any of your plugins, you must check by removing each by each to find out which one caused the problem

I had a same issue and in my case ANACONDA plugin caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

You must have css extended completions. That was the case of the problem in my case. Go to **Preferences** > **Package settings** and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

For m-series mac delete the old app. Download and install the lastest one.